# Real-time SQLite and PostgreSQL bi-directional synchronization using python

Tags: python, database, synchronization

Is there any python library that can keep a client-side SQLite database in sync with a server-side PostgreSQL database?

There are solutions for Java, such as Daffodil or SymmetricDS. Is there something similar for python?

Answer (score 1):

SymmetricDS is a server-side solution for synchronization that gets triggered regardless of which language is being used to access the database. You should still be able to use that to synchronize the databases, while using Python libraries to actually query them. I would recommend [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as a good database-independent query layer for Python.

Comment: The emphasis of my question is in finding out a python solution equivalent to SymmetricDS, not using SymmetricDS anyway. Appart from that, afaik SymmetricDS does not support SQLite. But thanks for trying to answer it though.

Comment: symmetricds claims to now support sqlite on android.